# What runs first - constructor or ionView...?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, page-lifecycle

In Ionic framework, what runs first is it the constructor or ionViewDidEnter? Is this guaranteed?

What about constructor vs each of the other events page lifecycle events? Is there any guarantee whether constructor or any of the ionic page lifecycle events will run first?

Comment: `constructor` is called first everytime in `Ionic` lifecycle then all other events executes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor() method is not a feature of Ionic, It's a feature of ES6 class (Typescript in most cases). So Ionic framework doesn't call the constructor method, It's javascript engines responsibility to call the constructor. So,
It's the first lifecycle event that is fired when the page is being initiated.

Now to answer your questions

*In Ionic framework, what runs first is it the constructor or ionViewDidEnter? Is this guaranteed?*

If the page is not loaded into the memory, then it's always the constructor which is called first. Followed by other life cycle events provided by Ionic(See the picture pasted below to see the order of events).

If the page is already loaded into the memory, then the constructor will not be called.
In this case, the ionViewCanEnter will be the first event to be fired,  then the ionViewWillEnter even will be fired and then the ionViewDidEnter event will be fired.

**Note**: ionViewDidLoad is only fired once when the page is loaded into the memory(like the constructor)

Next question,

*What about constructor vs each of the other events page lifecycle events? Is there any guarantee whether constructor or any of the ionic page lifecycle events will run first?*

As I mentioned earlier , The constructor will always be called first if the page hasn't been loaded. If it is already loaded, then the constructor won't be called.

Below diagram shows the order of Ionic Page life cycle events.

[image]

A bit of an explanation for each event.

**ionViewCanEnter**

> This event is an Ion Nav Guard Fired before entering into a view(page), allows you to control whether the view can
>   be accessed or not (returning true or false). If the page is already loaded into the memory, this will be the first event to be fired. If not, This method will be fired after the constructor.

**ionViewDidLoad**

> Fired only when a view is stored in memory. This event is NOT fired on
>   entering a view that is already cached. The difference between the constructor and IonViewDidLoad is that the constructor should be as thin as possible, meaning you should only be initializing the variables of your class. This is because making calls to REST API and initializing data in the constructor would cause the application to slow down as the creation of the object takes time. Whereas in ionViewDidLoad event you can be sure that all your variables & dependencies injected are available for use and it's also a good place to make REST API calls and initialize the data.

**ionViewWillEnter**

> This event is fired when entering a page before it becomes the active
>   one. You can use this event for tasks that has to be done every time
>   when a view is entered (ex: Updating a table).

**ionViewDidEnter**

> Fired when entering a page, after it becomes the active page.

**ionViewCanLeave**

> This event is also nav guard like ionViewCanEnter. This event is fired
>   before leaving a view, allows you to control whether the view can be
>   left or not.

**ionViewWillLeave**

> This event is fired when you leave a page. At this stage, your page is
>   still in an active state but it has been queued up to be removed and
>   you can no longer prevent the page from being transitioned away.

**ionViewDidLeave**

> At this state, the page has become inactive. It is important to note
>   that this event will be fired after ionViewDidEnter of the next page
>   has fired. You can use this method to save data or state that can be
>   used when this page is visited again ( Only if the page is not
>   destroyed).

**ionViewDidUnload**

> Fired when a view is going to be completely removed (after leaving a
>   non-cached view). This method can be used to free up the resources
>   that is no longer required

**Refernce**:https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/